# How can I assign values to the stack in NASM x86-64 without going out of bounds?

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64, nasm, stack-memory

I would like to understand how to correctly assign values on the stack in NASM x86-64

I would like to clarify something. Imagine we have an assembler program like this, with a prologue + epilogue and a reservation of 16 bytes:

```
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
sub rsp, 16
mov [rbp - 8], rdi
mov [rbp - 16], rsi
add rsp, 16
pop rbp
ret
```

What I would like to understand, in the convention it is marked that RSP points to the end of the last element allocated on the stack. How come I can attribute to [rbp - 16], rsi? Since this is the end of the segment I defined ?

Comment: It is as you say. `rsp` points to the last used (allocated) byte. Since `rsp = rbp - 16` you can of course write to `rbp - 16` and up. Note that due to negative offset `mov [rbp - 16], rsi` will write to `rbp - 16`, `rbp - 15`, ... `rbp - 9` all of which are in the allocated region.

Comment: Try running through the example with a specific stack pointer value to see where you're writing relative to what you've allocated. For example, use a hypothetical starting stack pointer value of 0x1018. Any memory address value at or above 0x1018 belongs to your function's callers, and you shouldn't be using that memory (without good reason).  During the `push rbp`, the stack pointer is adjusted to 0x1010, and the old `rbp` is written as qword to memory locations 0x1010-0x1017. After the `sub rsp, 16` the stack pointer is adjusted to 0x1000, and memory from 0x1000-0x100f is available to you.

Comment: The new `rbp` value is 0x1010, so `[rbp-16]` refers to 0x1000 and as qword then 0x1000-0x1007, while `[rbp-8]` as qword refers to memory locations 0x1008-0x100f.  Addresses below 0x1000 are not necessarily allocated to your function — but may be in the red zone depending on ABI of the system.

Answer (score 0):

> RSP points to the **end** of the last element allocated on the stack.

The word 'end' is causing confusion.

Normally, when looking at a chunk of memory, it 'begins' at the lowest address and it 'ends' at the highest address in the range.

```
0 ...  <-------------------------->  ...
       |                           |
       Begin                       End
```

The stack is different in that **the stack grows downward**. A new allocation that you make 'begins' at some higher address and 'ends' at a lower address. It is this 'end' that your quote talks about.

```
0 ...  <-------------------------->  ...
       |                           |
       End                         Begin
       New RSP                     Old RSP
       Top-Of-Stack
```

To add to the confusion, this lower address now gets named **Top-Of-Stack** which is definitely also not intuitive for the word 'top'. (None of the confusion would exist if only the stack grew upward...)

> ```
> push rbp
> mov rbp, rsp
> sub rsp, 16
> mov [rbp - 8], rdi
> mov [rbp - 16], rsi
> ```

Your code snippet contains 2 allocations of stack memory: `push rbp` requests 8 bytes, and `sub rsp, 16` requests 16 bytes. Once allocated, you are free to read/write from/to this memory. In case of `push rbp` it is the CPU that writes to the memory.

```
0 ...  <---RSI------RDI------RBP-->  ...
       |         |        |        |
       End       |        |        Begin
       New RSP   |        |        Old RSP
       New Top-Of-Stack   |        Old Top-Of-Stack
       |         |        |
       [RBP-16]  [RBP-8]  [RBP]
```